# How to use Quartz in JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, quartz-scheduler, jboss5.x

I'm looking for solution to use QuartzScheduler in EJB3 Stateless bean, how can I access instance of Scheduler in EJB3 from InitialContext?

I tried

```
Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) ctx.lookup("DefaultQuartzScheduler");
```

but it returned NameNotFoundException, also i tried name: Quartz, Scheduler and caught the same exception

Enviroment: JBoss 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Have you first created the quartz-service which runs in the jboss.That service will associate the JNDI name to the quartzSchedler.
You have to look up ONLY that name in your codefor everything else you will get Name not found exception